# Social framework sharing not working with Twitter

Tags: ios, twitter, share, slcomposeviewcontroller, social-framework

I am facing one issue. When I'm trying to make post via Twitter with Social framework, and Twitter card is appears, I tap "Post", card disappears but in Twitter account this post not shows.

```
    let post = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)!
    post.title = "MyApp"
    post.setInitialText("\(title ?? "")\n\(description!)\n")
    post.add(url)
    post.add(image)
    post.completionHandler = { (result) in
        print(result)
    }

    self.present(post, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

About month ago all has been worked, and code hasn't been changed.

Message in output

> SLRemoteComposeViewController: (this may be harmless) viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={Terminated=disconnect method}

Facebook by the way is working well

Comment: If twitter app is installed in your phone then make sure that you are logged-in in it, you can do it from setting app!

Comment: @Lion, yes, I checked, I was Logged-in. I even tried logg-in second time but it not helped